# Nodes not displaying, console shows xml parsing error

Tags: rundeck

I'm having troubles viewing my nodes in a fresh rundeck install.  resources.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <node name="fooweb01"
          description="fooweb01" tags="foo,us-east,webserver"
          osFamily="unix" osName="Linux"
          hostname="fooweb01"  username="user"
    />
    <node name="fooweb02"
          description="fooweb02" tags="foo,us-east,webserver"
          osFamily="unix" osName="Linux"
          hostname="fooweb02"  username="user"
    />
    <node name="fooweb03"
          description="fooweb03" tags="foo,us-east,webserver"
          osFamily="unix" osName="Linux"
          hostname="fooweb03"  username="user"
    />
    <node name="fooweb04"
          description="fooweb04" tags="foo,us-east,webserver"
          osFamily="unix" osName="Linux"
          hostname="fooweb04"  username="user"
    />
    <node name="foocorp01"
          description="foocorp01" tags="foo,us-east,corporate"
          osFamily="unix" osName="Linux"
          hostname="foocorp01"  username="user"
    />
    <node name="foocorp02"
          description="foocorp02" tags="foo,us-east,corporate"
          osFamily="unix" osName="Linux"
          hostname="foocorp02"  username="user"
    />
    <node name="foopartner01"
          description="foopartner01" tags="foo,us-east,partner-api"
          osFamily="unix" osName="Linux"
          hostname="foopartner01"  username="user"
    />
    <node name="foodb01"
          description="foodb01" tags="foo,us-east,cluster-node"
          osFamily="unix" osName="Linux"
          hostname="foodb01"  username="user"
    />
    <node name="foodb02"
          description="foodb02" tags="foo,us-east,cluster-node"
          osFamily="unix" osName="Linux"
          hostname="foodb02"  username="user"
    />
    <node name="foodb03"
          description="foodb03" tags="foo,us-east,cluster-node"
          osFamily="unix" osName="Linux"
          hostname="foodb03"  username="user"
    />
    <node name="foolb01"
          description="foolb03" tags="foo,us-east,haproxy"
          osFamily="unix" osName="Linux"
          hostname="foolb03"  username="user"
    />
    <node name="foolb02"
          description="foolb03" tags="foo,us-east,haproxy"
          osFamily="unix" osName="Linux"
          hostname="foolb03"  username="user"
    />
    <node name="foojobs01"
          description="foojobs03" tags="foo,us-east,docker-services"
          osFamily="unix" osName="Linux"
          hostname="foojobs03"  username="user"
    />
    <node name="foomonitor"
          description="Ops Host" tags="foo,us-east,monitor"
          osFamily="unix" osName="Linux"
          hostname="foomonitor"  username="user"
    />
</project>
```

project.properties in the same folder

```
project.resources.file=/var/lib/rundeck/projects/cron_jobs/etc/resources.xml
resources.source.1.type=file
resources.source.1.config.file=/var/lib/rundeck/projects/cron_jobs/etc/resources.xml
resources.source.1.config.format=resourcexml
resources.source.1.config.requireFileExists=true
resources.source.1.config.includeServerNode=true
resources.source.1.config.generateFileAutomatically=true
```

`project.resources.file=/var/lib/rundeck/projects/cron_jobs/etc/resources.xml` was a recent test that didn't help.  When i load `project/cron_jobs/nodes` in the browser console i see

```
XML Parsing Error: syntax error
Location: https://example.org/project/cron_jobs/nodes
Line Number 1: Column 1:
```

There are no errors in the logs, i have reimported the project each time i make a change to the file, which has not been frequent.

This is driving me crazy, looking for another pair of eyes.  All other pages work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rundeck enumerates their model sources (for example: 1=your `resources.xml` file, 2=ansible inventory, 3=ec2 nodes, etc.) in your case, the first one is the `resources.xml` file.

Just delete the `project.resources.file=/var/lib/rundeck/projects/cron_jobs/etc/resources.xml` line and save.

I created a new project (on Rundeck 3.3.10), deleted the first model source (local), added your `resources.xml` file (which works like a charm) as first model source and the `project.properties` looks in the following way:

```
#Fri Mar 26 08:53:10 CLST 2021
#edit below
project.disable.executions=false
project.disable.schedule=false
project.execution.history.cleanup.batch=500
project.execution.history.cleanup.enabled=false
project.execution.history.cleanup.retention.days=60
project.execution.history.cleanup.retention.minimum=50
project.execution.history.cleanup.schedule=0 0 0 1/1 * ? *
project.jobs.gui.groupExpandLevel=1
project.name=ProjectEXAMPLE
project.nodeCache.enabled=true
project.nodeCache.firstLoadSynch=true
project.output.allowUnsanitized=false
project.ssh-authentication=privateKey
project.ssh-command-timeout=0
project.ssh-connect-timeout=0
project.ssh-keypath=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
resources.source.1.config.file=/path/to/your/resources.xml
resources.source.1.config.format=resourcexml
resources.source.1.config.generateFileAutomatically=true
resources.source.1.config.writeable=true
resources.source.1.type=file
service.FileCopier.default.provider=jsch-scp
service.NodeExecutor.default.provider=jsch-ssh
```

And the [nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkYaw.jpg) on "Nodes" page.

Comment: Thank you.  After reading this and knowing the file line was my last attempt.  I deleted the project from the UI, hopefully cleaning up cruft, created anew, same name, deleted the "local" source from the UI, which allowed me to configure the file source, and i can now see my nodes.  When i wrote this i was 99% of the way there, thanks for the push!

Comment: Excellent! any time!